# R error in matrix 5 arguments passed to .Internal(matrix) which requires 7

Tags: r, matrix

For whatever reason, I keep getting the error message `5 arguments passed to .Internal(matrix) which requires 7` whenever I try to run the following code:

```
library(randomForest)
set.seed(647)
myiris <- cbind(iris[1:4], matrix(runif(508 * nrow(iris)), nrow(iris), 508))
```

Through searching, I've found a couple of other people who've had similar problems, but none of the solutions for those individuals seems to have worked for me. The version of R I am running is as follows:

```
    R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01) -- "Security Blanket"
    Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
    ISBN 3-900051-07-0
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

When I run searchpaths(), I get the following:

```
searchpaths()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"                                                "C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/R/win-library/2.15/randomForest"
 [3] "tools:rstudio"                                             "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/stats"                
 [5] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/graphics"              "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/grDevices"            
 [7] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/utils"                 "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/datasets"             
 [9] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/methods"               "Autoloads"                                                
[11] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/library/base"
```

I am guessing that the problem somehow stems from [11], but am unsure how to permanently change it. I uninstalled all previous versions of R on my computer and reinstalled 2.15-3, but I still get:

```
[11] "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-215~1.3/library/base"
```

Any help solving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce this error on 2.15.2 and OS X.

Comment: Works for me too, R 2.15.2 and Windows 7.

Comment: If you write `matrix`, and look for line starting with `.Internal(matrix(`, how many arguments there is?

Comment: when I type `matrix` I get the following: `.Internal(matrix(data, nrow, ncol, byrow, dimnames))`  I remember someone else mentioning this, but whatever solution they found didn't work for me. I have run `update.packages()` (and was running the program as an administrator), so it seems unlikely that this is the problem. 
Regarding those who were unable to reproduce the error, this is why it is frustrating. On another computer at work, I have no issues, it is only with my personal computer at home.

Comment: based on your searchpath you seem to use RStudio? Do you get same error if you try the original Rgui? You could perhaps also test R patched version: http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/R-2.15.3patched-win.exe

Comment: Thanks for the response Hemmo. I get the same response when using the original Rgui and appear to have the same issue after installing the R patched version you linked to. Thanks again for trying to help!

Comment: I can replicate this if I copy an old version of the base library into a newer version of R (2.12.2 copied into 2.15.1), there are howver a number of other warnings that are printed when I start up R. I think you need to re install R, and don't copy over the library folder from an older version (if your updating procedure has some variant of this)

Comment: Hi mnel, I've tried reinstalling R (and prior to reinstalling, I deleted all files related to R [including the x86 and personal libraries] that I could find) and yet still have the same problem. Any other thoughts? Any thoughts on another way that I can check for some more residual R files (somewhere) that might be causing the problem?

Comment: Does anyone have any additional thoughts on this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the problem is in searchpaths, the path for base looks always weird if there is R version number in path.

You probably have too old version of randomForest or some other package. Try `update.packages()` for updating your packages.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem isn't with the randomForest (or other package) as near as I can tell because (even though I forgot to mention it) I had previously run `update.packages()` (while running the program as an administrator) and still have the issue. The issue is there even when there are no packages (other than the typical ones loaded when you start R) loaded. As you noted above, it probably has something to do with the fact that my `.Internal(matrix(` only lists 5 elements instead of 7. Why this should be the case given that I've reinstalled (after removing), I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

In the event that this might help someone else... It appears (for whatever reason...) that I had a 'matrix' function defined in my default workspace (~.RData) file (saved, by default, in the Documents folder and unfortunately, despite uninstalling and reinstalling the program several times, I never thought to look in the Documents folder for orphaned R files).

As I almost never save the workspace (the file was last dated in 2011), I never even thought to look for the problem there (and back in 2011, I doubt I even knew how to write a function...). In any case, after deleting the 'matrix' function from my workspace and resaving the workspace, I no longer have the problem.

This answer also pertains to the following post: [R (2.15.3; Vista x64) matrix base package: Error 5 arguments passed to .Internal(matrix) which requires 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15328610/r-2-15-3-vista-x64-matrix-base-package-error-5-arguments-passed-to-internal)