# R (2.15.3; Vista x64) matrix base package: Error 5 arguments passed to .Internal(matrix) which requires 7

Tags: r, function, matrix, radix

While several have indicated that this question is a duplicate positing (it is, but despite hemmo's assistance we were not able to solve the problem...). In this posting, I 1) provided some additional information on the problem I am having and 2) was asking how I might go about editing the base code for the matrix function to the code that is shown at the bottom of the post.

Could anyone tell me how I might go about updating the matrix function in the base package? I am running a clean install 2.15.3 (and I deleted all R related files I could find (from previous installations) and also tried cleaning the registry prior to re-installing 2.15.3), but keep getting the following error whenever I try to use `matrix`:

```
cells <- c(1,26,24,68)
rnames <- c("R1", "R2")
cnames <- c("C1", "C2") 
mymatrix <- matrix(cells, nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE,
dimnames=list(rnames, cnames))
```

`Error in matrix(cells, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(rnames,  : 
  5 arguments passed to .Internal(matrix) which requires 7`

Interestingly, if I type `mymatrix <- as.matrix(cells, nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE,
    dimnames=list(rnames, cnames))` I get no errors, but the output is incorrect:

```
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]   26
[3,]   24
[4,]   68
```

When I type `matrix` alone, I get the following:

```
function (data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL) 
{
data <- as.vector(data)
if (missing(nrow)) 
    nrow <- ceiling(length(data)/ncol)
else if (missing(ncol)) 
    ncol <- ceiling(length(data)/nrow)
.Internal(matrix(data, nrow, ncol, byrow, dimnames))
}
<environment: namespace:base>
```

From the couple of previous posts I've been able to find on a similar error message, it seems like typing `matrix` should result in the following:

```
function (data = NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 1, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL) 
{ 
if (is.object(data) || !is.atomic(data)) 
    data <- as.vector(data) 
.Internal(matrix(data, nrow, ncol, byrow, dimnames, missing(nrow), 
    missing(ncol))) 
} 
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Does anyone know how I can edit the `matrix` function in the base package such that it looks like the code immediately above (with 7 arguments)? Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the results of `sessionInfo()` in your question.  The `base` package is what is installed when you install R. It appears as if you are using an earlier version of `base` but an uptodate version of the internal function `matrix`. What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: I can replicate this if I copy the base library from R 2.12.2 to R 2.15.x -- with lots of other warnings on startup though. I don't believe this would be an issue if this was a clean installation of R.

Comment: What happens when you type `help(package= 'base')`, what version do you see?

Comment: mnel, thanks for the quick response. Here is the sessionInfo information. `R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base  ` If I type `help(package = "base"), it fires up my web browser and basically lists the documentation for base version 2.15.3.

Comment: A long time ago I upgraded from 2.10.x, but because of this problem I've been having, I uninstalled all previous versions of R and did a clean install, so I don't know why I should still have the base library from 2.12.2.

Comment: For an answer to this question, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251793/r-error-in-matrix-5-arguments-passed-to-internalmatrix-which-requires-7/16494638#16494638